# perl Inline::Java with JAXB

Tags: java, perl, jaxb, inline

Hi I am not sure if anybody has any experience with perl Inline::Java to call Java JAXB . Basically, I have added some code in my perl script to call some of my Java API that calls JAXB.

```
System.out.println(“before…”);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("SomeXMLPackage");
System.out.println(“after…”);
```

and it fails on the JAXB statement. I then added Debug and AUTOSTUDY  option in perl like below

```
use Inline (
    Java => 'DATA',
    J2SDK => $ENV{JAVA_HOME},
    CLASSPATH => 'classes',
    AUTOSTUDY => 1,
    DEBUG => 4,
);
```

then I see
    [java][3]   packet sent is ok java_object:1:1:javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    [perl][3]   packet recv is ok java_object:1:1:javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    [perl][3]   checking if stub is array...
    [perl][3]   perl doesn't know about 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException' ('perlAPI::javax::xml::bind::JAXBException')
    [perl][2]  autostudying javax.xml.bind.JAXBException...
    [perl][3]   perl doesn't know about 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException' ('perlAPI::javax::xml::bind::JAXBException')
    [perl][3]   reporting on javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

I hope perl inline works with JAXB 

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out. Here is the answer. Bascially, need to create a class loader.

ClassLoader cl = SomeXMLPackage.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("SomeXMLPackage", cl);